# Would usage in this particular sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, sentence-construction, modal-verbs

1. Learning an instrument is not as easy as one **would** wish.

What is the use of "would" here and what is the meaning of these sentence?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means that we would like it if it was easier to learn how to play a musical instrument. Would is a modal verb used to express hopes, desires and so on; "I would like it if learning an instrument was easy."

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/would

"One" in this sentence is a pronoun referring to people in general, or perhaps the speaker in particular.